# How do I set fixed div height 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3

- Header
- Content
- Footer

They all set position **fixed**.

How to set  (content) height automatically to be 100%?

The problem is the last text on the content section is hidden by footer div.

How to **set content** div height automatically calculate 100% - footer height?

```css
html,body { height:100%; }
  .wrapper { position:relative; width:100%; height:100%}
  .box1 { position:fixed; top:0;left:0; width:100%; height:30px; background:red}
  .box2 { position:fixed; top:30px;left:0; width:100%; height:100%; overflow-y:auto; background:gray}
  .box3 { position:fixed; bottom:0;left:0; width:100%; height:30px; background:blue}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box1">head</div>
  <div class="box2">content>last text</div>
  <div class="box3">foot</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add height:calc(100% - 60px); to `box2` for minus header and footer both height and set overflow-y:hidden to html,body so you can get fixed div 100% height without scroll

```css
html,body { height:100%; overflow-y:hidden; }
.wrapper { position:relative; width:100%; height:100%}

.box1 { position:fixed; top:0;left:0; width:100%; height:30px; background:red}
.box2 { position:fixed; top:30px;left:0; width:100%; height:calc(100% - 60px); overflow-y:auto; background:gray}
.box3 { position:fixed; bottom:0;left:0; width:100%; height:30px; background:blue}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="box1">head</div>
<div class="box2">content<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>last text</div>
<div class="box3">foot</div>

</div>
```

Comment: @rinnrinn Welcome Mate

Answer (score 0):

`calc()` CSS function lets you perform calculations while setting height, width or other property.

For your case, `height: calc(100% - 30px);` would help you out.

for more detail about `calc()`, please refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).

Answer (score 0):

To fixed height or width you can use `calc(100% - 30px);`..
To handle dynamically changing height/width, You need to calculate with Javascript like this....

```js
var screenHeight = window.innerHeight;
var headerH = document.getElementById("header").offsetHeight;
var footerH = document.getElementById("footer").offsetHeight;

document.getElementById("content").style.height = ((screenHeight - headerH) - footerH) + "px";
document.getElementById("content").style.top = headerH + "px";
```

```css
.header{
  background-color:red;
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
}

.footer{
  background-color:red;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
}

.content{
  position:fixed;
  left:0px;
  background-color:yellow;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header" id="header">header</div>
<div class="content" id="content">content</div>
<div class="footer" id="footer">footer</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of height, use `bottom: 30px;` for box2. it will work.